# Should the jmf executable be downloaded?

Tags: java, jmf

On the installation page of [JMF](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-downloads-java-client-downloads.html#7372-jmf-2.1.1e-oth-JPR) they allow you to download an executable download file for windows. My OS is windows however i have downloaded the zip file from the `Cross-platform Java` option where the java libraries are located. I have added the libraries to Eclipse and JMF works fine there. However i followed a tutorial where they both installed the executable file and added the java libraries to eclipse. My question is: Do we need to download the JMF executable if JMF works fine with the java libraries?